# Compatibility between libraries built with different versions of XCode / iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've moved a project from XCode 4 to XCode 5 and from building against iOS 6 SDK to iOS 7 SDK. One of the libs I use, I have a prebuilt version targeting iOS 4.3 which worked fine in XCode 4.

In XCode 5, my app now runs fine on the iOS6 simulator, but I get a crash inside the library every time with iOS7 simulator. I'm looking to understand why this is and how different library builds are[n't] compatible with each other... the library is not using any iOS functionality as it's a cross-platform C++ lib, so why it would crash in one simulator but not the other is a bit perplexing.

Comment: Have you looked at the crash log?

Answer (score 0):

> it's a cross-platform C++ lib

This might be your problem. C++ does not have a stable ABI, so libraries should always be built using the compiler that builds the executable they're linked against.

Comment: Does this explain how it only crashes running on one simulator but works on the other one?

Comment: No obvious reason, but it's possible that there's some undefined behaviour that's only causing problems in one environment. It's the only potential issue I can see from the information you've provided, anyway.